# Static charge behavior (in ref to Grob's Basic Electronics book, 13th Ed, p33)

Tags: charge, static

I have a question pertaining to the aforementioned book in a section titled "Potential between Different Charges".  The paragraph goes as follows:

[image]

> When one charge is different from the other, there must be a difference of potential between them.  For instance, consider a positive charge of 3 C shown at the right in Fig. 1–7a. The charge has a certain amount of potential, corresponding to the amount of work this charge can do.  The work to be done is moving some electrons, as illustrated.  Assume that a charge of 1 C can move three electrons. Then the charge of +3 C can attract nine electrons toward the right. However, the charge of -1 C at the opposite side can attract three electrons toward the left. The net result, then, is that six electrons can be moved toward the right to the more positive charge.  In Fig. 1-7b, one charge is +2 C, and the other charge is neutral with 0 C.  For the difference of 2 C, again 2 x 3 or 6 electrons can be attracted to the positive side.  In Fig. 1-7c, the difference between the charges is still 2 C. The +1 C attracts three electrons to the right side. The -1 C repels three electrons to the right side also. This effect is really the same as attracting six electrons."

The book then proceeds to say:

> Therefore, the net number of electrons moved in the direction of the
> more positive charge depends on the difference of potential between
> the two charges. This potential difference is the same for all three
> cases, as shown in Fig. 1–7. Potential difference is often abbreviated
> PD. The only case without any potential difference between charges
> occurs when they both have the same polarity and are equal in amount.
> Then the repelling and attracting forces cancel, and no work can be
> done in moving electrons between the two identical charges.

So I am left a bit confused.  If charge moves as stated, then in Fig 1-7a, there will be a neutral charge on the body on the left and a +1 C on the body on the right.  So, a charge will still exist between the two bodies and so what stops further movement occurring between the two bodies?  Why would the charge movement just "stop" when there is still a difference of potential between the bodies?  The same goes for the other two examples in Fig 1-7 b and c.

Please bear with me as I am clearly not a physicist so please excuse my lack of knowledge!  Any help, at this level of understanding, will be gratefully received.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When the text says:

> Assume that a charge of 1 C can move three electrons.

and then later:

> Therefore, the net number of electrons moved in the direction of the more positive charge depends on the difference of potential between the two charges.

it seems that they are saying a 1C charge difference will move three electrons and only three electrons even though there will still be a charge imbalance after those three electrons have moved.

What's really going on is that an electron near a charged plate will feel a force proportional to amount of charge on that plate. When it is between two charged plates you have to add the forces exerted on the electron from both plates. This means the total force on the electron is proportional to the difference in charge between the two plates. Forces are what make objects move, and every electron between the two plates will feel the same force.

Maybe the book doesn't want to talk about force and are using the idea of "being able to move X number of electrons" as a substitute for it.

The way older tube TV and computer CRTs work is a real-life example of how charges on a plate affect moving electrons. An electron gun is used to emit a beam of electrons between two charged plates. The charges on the plates exert a force to the moving electrons bending their trajectory. The amount of deflection is directly related to the charge difference between the two plates. A tube TV or CRT constantly adjusts the charges on the deflection plates to move the beam across the screen.

[image]

(Source: https://circuitglobe.com/electrostatic-deflection-in-crt.html )

Comment: Hello Erik.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.  Your response does help and I shall follow it up to pacify myself and then move on.  I think you are correct that the book is abstracting away much of the detail of what is actually happening 'under-the-bonnet'; the target audience being engineers rather than physicists.  I am unable to register a +ve vote for you as I currently have a 'zero reputation' on this site - so it tells me!  Sounds about right, then!  Thanks for your help.